# AD authentication in AD forest

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory

In an Active Directory consisting of forests containing various sub domains and case where the UPN (user@domainame.com) does not reflect the true domain where the user resides, how can the user be authenticated in this scenario?

Example: user upn is `user@xyz.com` residing in `domain1.xyz.com`. `domain1` has trust relations with `domain2.xyz.com`.

How can we validate the `user@xyz.com` in `domain2` against domain 1 using just the username and password?

Is `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` API able to authenticate the user in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, it will work but you need to set the principle context to your domain. you have to have your own logic to identify the domain of the user either from email id (in your case) or else 'domain\userid' if userid used scenario.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/73549/active-directory-cross-domain-authentication.

Comment: how to find the correct domain. Is trying to authenticate against every domain in the AD forest a reasonable apporach?

Comment: How are you planning to authenticate? If you use Windows authentication, then everything is taken care of for you. What is your application? (web app? desktop app?)

Comment: It is not windows authentication, the application validates the credentials a credentials database.